# Format not preserved when copying text from one bookmark to another

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I'm trying to copy text from one Word document to another Word document using bookmarks dynamically through C# code. I'm able to retrieve only the data from the bookmark of one document and insert it into a other document, but the format of the text is changing.

For example, if I add some colour, font in the source document bookmark, the same format is not copied into the target document's bookmark; only the text is copied.

```
//getting the text from source documents bookmark.
string text = Document1.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objI).Range.Text.ToString();
//copying the text to Document 2's bookmark
objWordDoc1.Bookmarks.get_Item(booktest).Range.Text = text;
```

How can I copy the formatting too?

Comment: Are the two documents open at the same time? Is using the clipboard OK for this task (like copy and paste)?

Comment: ya first.. opening source document,copying the text from the bookmark to a variable...then opening target document and inserting the text...

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Use copy and paste, something like

   ```
   // Copy
   Document1.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objI).Range.Copy();

   // Paste
   objWordDoc1.Bookmarks.get_Item(booktest).Range.PasteAndFormat(WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting);
   ```
2. Work with Formatted text property ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.formattedtext(v=office.11).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.formattedtext%28v=office.11%29.aspx). (I didn't test this)

   `Range text = Document1.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objI).Range.FormattedText;
   objWordDoc1.Bookmarks.get_Item(booktest).Range = FormattedText;`

Comment: Hi Vadim.....Thanks for the reply....but its not working ....by using the above code..its not copying the text..instead its copying some junk text...

Comment: The code was meant to be an example of how this can be done. I've modified it into something that should work. Let me know it it's ok.